# OS X Avatar system

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there some kind of library i could use to implement avatars in my app for Mac OS X ?

I was thinking there might be something build-in since the User Accounts prefs pane uses avatar for your login screen etc.

Anything?

Comment: An avatar is just an image. What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for avatars in OS X (that I'm aware of) but if you want the users login icon then this should help: [Where does the Mac store account pictures?](https://superuser.com/questions/56413/where-does-the-mac-store-account-pictures)